# ReactJS/Typescript upgrade changed type of Children from any to ReactNode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, children

Recently trying to update from TypeScript 2.3 (I know) to 3.3 and running into a problem with ReactJS, specifically the type of props.children.

```
this.props.children.map((s)=>{return <span>{s.prop1} - {s.prop2}</span>});
```

it used to work just dandy, but now 'children' is a ReactNode type instead of any.  This causes the compiler to choke out on 'map' does not exist on type 'ReactNode'.

Can any of you point me in the direction to overcome this roadblock?

Comment: this.props.children may not be an array anymore so you'll have to type-guard accordingly.

Comment: and that is accomplished by....because in my case, it will be...always.